# check if one class is being referenced by another class via bytecode

Tags: java, bytecode

It's relatively easy to figure out if one class inherits from another class. Is there a way to figure out whether one class is included within another class through looking at the byte code alone? Are there tools to do that?

Comment: One can find the imports, but literal constants are copied, so their imports disappear. This missing class depency is also a problem for the compiler, as when the original constant is given a different value, no recompile on the importing class will be triggered.

Comment: What do you mean with “one class is included within another class”? If you mean “one class is being referenced by another class”, as your title suggests, why don’t you write exactly that? But then, the answer is trivial, a tautology. Of course, whether byte code references another class, can be told by looking at the byte code alone.

Comment: Classes can also be accessed through reflection and this usages can't be determined in the general case.